# soft keyboard change size of my layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a problem with layout (edittext and button inside) when soft keyboard appears after edittext click. Whole layout is rezising (become smaller) and element inside (edittext) are to small. Situation looks like that, I have 2 layouts, where first takes 50% of screen and under is antoher layout. In that second layout I have all editext and buttons and I wanna to that layout stay in original size - just put that layout higher when keyboard appears. I try ajdustPan, adjustResize and other and have no idea how fix it.

I using % in that layout to specify element height, also I put ScrollView as first layout, but this also not working. My layout hierarchy:

- ScrollView

  - RelativeLayout

    - RelativeLayout (50% - space size) (alignBottom space)
    - space
    - LinearLayout   (50% - space size) (layout_below space)

In LinearLayout I have 2 Edittext.

Anyone have suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest file set android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustPan"  in the Activity tag. Hope this will solve your problem.

I have tried for the .xml file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/container"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="removeFragment"
            android:text="Remove" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/container"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="removeFragment"
            android:text="Remove" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="removeFragment"
            android:text="Remove" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustPan"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I think you just want to shift the layout up when keyboard opens. android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustPan" is working fine for me.

Comment: yes I wanna shift the layout , but stateUnchanged|adjustPan, not working properly in my case:/